# Including external libraries in Android Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

My app is able to run without any issues during testing etc. But when I export out apk compiled with ProGuard, there are issues like random crashing and some features not working as expected.

I not sure is it due to the external jar libraries I have included in the project which is not properly configured in Proguard.

I have included the following in the proguard-android.txt file. I have two libraries so I added these:

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.net.** { *; }
-keep class org.jsoup.** { *; }
```

Is it the correct way? Is there any other way?

Comment: what are the libraries in your libs/lib folder? you might need to skip them.

Comment: @moh.sukhni The two libraries I have stated above: apache and jsoup. The jars are in /libs folder

Comment: Sometime, you may need to keep some attributes
 `-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod`
In my case with jackson library

Comment: try to add the following lines to your progaurd config file. 

-dontwarn org.apache.commons.net.**
-dontwarn org.jsoup.**

Answer (score 0):

To add libraries just add `-libraryjars ../libs/<libname>`
After that you may need to keep classes and interfaces based on the errors you receive